# Android Studio "Generate Signed APK Wizard" doesn't run Proguard

Tags: android-studio, proguard

I'm running Android Studio 0.3.2 and I'm able to correctly generate a signed APK for my application through the Generate Signed APK wizard. Now I wanted to try out the option to additionally run Proguard through that wizard, checking the box 'Run Proguard' and specifying the default proguard-android-optimize.txt config file, as well as a local proguard-project.txt file in the config file paths box below the checkbox. I also made sure the build variant is a Release variant. However after clicking the Finish button an APK is created without errors but apparently it is exactly the same APK as the one obtained with 'Run Proguard' unchecked. Proguard is not called at all. What am I missing here?

Cheers,
Tom.